# Create Table (new columns) and columns from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

So For example. I have 1 table
and the name of the table is `Suppliers`
Contains :

```
 1. SupplierName
 2. SupplierID
```

I want to create another new table name `Contracts`
which contain new columns for

```
 1. ContractID (new column)
 2. SupplierID(from "Suppliers" table)
 3. ContractValue (new column)
```

How do i  do it?

I have researched and most of them told me to use Create table and then select, But it wont work and also ive tried alter table but still not working.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Contracts (
  ContractID INT NOT NULL, 
SELECT SupplierID 
FROM Suppliers,
  ContractValue INT NOT NULL, 
  ContractStart DATE NOT NULL)
```

These codes are not working so I'm not sure what is the solution.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Contracts (
  ContractID INT NOT NULL, 
(SELECT SupplierID 
FROM Suppliers),
  ContractValue INT NOT NULL, 
  ContractStart DATE NOT NULL)
```

I expect the result to be new table with `ContractID` (new column), `SupplierID` (from table `Suppliers`) and another new column named `ContractValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of Select query result set as a table or data grid.

So "SELECT [some fields] FROM [some table]" returns data grid where each row contains some fields from the table.

Therefore you can define table as select query with data OR alternatively specify the structure and create empty table. Most likely you don't want to mix those two approaches.

In your case, SupplierID field of contract table is a reference to SupplierID of Supplier table. In SQL it's called "foreign key". Theoretically you can use select statement in order to create new table and when you play a lot with database queries, you'll choose most convenient and faster way depending on your needs.

But when you start learning, it's better to create an empty table with structure and then insert data using new fields and existing data for the foreign key.

Therefore, the query will be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Contracts ( 
    ContractID INT NOT NULL,
    SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
    ContractValue INT,
    ContractStart DATE
);
```

And then you can insert data using existing values from supplier table:

```
INSERT INTO Contracts (SupplierID)
SELECT SupplierID FROM Suppliers
```

Of course this is very simplified description

First, you have to specify ContractID as primary key. Then the query above will work only if you specify primary key as auto increment value, otherwise you have to use some logic and specify it explicitly.

In addition you have to specify default values if you want to use NOT NULL fields.

You can also specify SupplierID as foreign key, so only existing values will be added and some other integrity relationships will be supported.

See any MySQL or SQL documentation for details.

Comment: Aloha, thank you for your comments, however, there is an error for the insert data code "Error 1: could not execute statement due to a constraint failure (19 NOT NULL constraint failed: Contracts.ContractID)"

Comment: right, because ContractID id is not NULL

you can simply fix the error by removing NOT NULL after ContractID in the CREATE TABLE statement

However this is not a great way to do in SQL. What you need to do is to specify the field as primary key and auto increment value. You can also specify some dummy value under INSERT statement. This is up to your business logic and you must understand what you are doing. Therefore you need to read documentation and select what is better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the below way could solve your problem

1. Make a copy of `Suppliers` table
2. Delete unnecessary column from the copied table
3. Add new column that you want to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CTAS` command.

```
CREATE TABLE Contracts as
SELECT 
0 as ContractID,
SupplierID,
0 as ContractValue, 
now() as ContractStart
FROM Suppliers;
```

This will create a table with all fields. The default value is to specify the `dataType`. You can update the table with relevant value or have a `join` in the select clause itself.

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax for creating a table from another table is as follows

**CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS
   SELECT [ column1, column2...columnN ]
   FROM EXISTING_TABLE_NAME
   [ WHERE ]**

Here, column1, column2... are the fields of the existing table and the same would be used to create fields of the new table.

**Example**
Following is an example, which would create a table SALARY using the CUSTOMERS table and having the fields customer ID and customer SALARY −

**SQL> CREATE TABLE SALARY AS
   SELECT ID, SALARY
   FROM CUSTOMERS;**

Answer (score 0):

last week I did, as you want to do.
Only two steps I was followed:

1. Export existing table.
2. Open in notepad++ and change the existing table name, add my new columns and Import.

Thanks